# Why is my Enter VR button missing or misplaced in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I am using A-Frame, but I cannot see the Enter VR button which is usually on the bottom right corner. Thus I cannot enter VR or fullscreen.

[image]

How can I make it show up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your scene is wrapped in a `<div>` then you may have to play with the styling your container. `<a-scene>` is `position: relative` by default. The canvas and the Enter VR button are `position: absolute` by default.

This is common if you are using React which requires a render container, or if you are using `embedded` scenes and putting that in a `div`.

Try setting the container styles `position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;`.

Comment: @ngokevin - this is exactly the issue I had in vue.js and I'd already done this. But in A-Frame 0.7.1, setting the height of the container to 100% breaks  the grab/move behavior on the desktop (even with pointer-events:none) and covers my view in the inspector.

Answer (score 2):

Using React, I simply told the initial render to use `document.body` rather than to create a container/div element to hold my AFrameReact components in. This resolved the issue fine for me and the enter VR mode button became visible once again.

Full example:
`ReactDOM.render(<World />,document.body);`